# PHP - ZipArchive - Does not work with "Winzip version 9"

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am trying to unzip a .zip file by my code. I am using ZipArchive for that one. It is wokring fine but only problem is, when I add zip file which is zipped by "winzip version 9", it extracts empty folder.

Any Idea why it is happening ?

below is my code :

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$x = $zip->open($file_to_open);

if ($x === true) 
{

    $zip->extractTo($target . $unique_folder);
    $zip->close();

} else {

    die("There was a problem opening zip. Please try again!");

}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about WinZip 9, but I know that WinZIP 10 supports new compression methods beyond the standard, age-old Deflate (eg. Bzip2, PPMd, etc.).

Last I checked, InfoZIP (the regular `unzip` command) doesn't support them while p7zip `7z x filename.zip` does support at least some of them, so testing your archive with them is one way you could narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have fixed it using  SSH  "unzip" command.